# if statement is not executing properly when criteria is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript

I am creating criteria inside if statement dynamically and storing in Profile_Filter varabile but when I run it against an array, it adds all the record to my temp array instead of adding matched records..

```
var Profile_Filter = "";

if ($("#DoctorNameDropDown option:selected").text() != "- Select One -") {
  Profile_Filter += 'gAssessorsCompanyAssociationsArray[i].Name == $("#DoctorNameDropDown option:selected").val()';
}

if ($("#Degree").val() != "") {
  var Degree_Filter = "";
  var Degree = $("#Degree").val().split(";");

  for (var i = 0; i < Degree.length; i++) {
    if (Degree[i] == "") {
      Degree.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }

  if (Degree.length > 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Degree.length; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        Degree_Filter += '(gAssessorsCompanyAssociationsArray[i].Degree.indexOf("' + Degree[j] + '") > 0';
      } else {
        Degree_Filter += ' && gAssessorsCompanyAssociationsArray[i].indexOf("' + Degree[j] + '") > 0';
      }
    }
    Degree_Filter += ")";
  } else Degree_Filter += '(gAssessorsCompanyAssociationsArray[i].Degree.indexOf("' + Degree[0] + '") > 0';

  if (Profile_Filter != "") Profile_Filter += " && " + Degree_Filter; else Profile_Filter += Degree_Filter;
}

var temp = [];

for (var i = 0; i < gAssessorsCompanyAssociationsArray.length; i++) {
  if (Profile_Filter) alert(gAssessorsCompanyAssociationsArray[i].Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your `Profile_Filter` variable **does not contain** any executable code; it just contains a simple string that may look like Javascript code but that is not actually interpreted.

When using this string variable as a boolean expression in an if-statement, the interpreter simply checks if the string "is true" (in the case of strings this means checking whether the string has a length > 0).

In order to actually execute the code stored in your variable inside the if-statement, you can use the `eval` function (but **please** also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) to learn why using `eval` is generally a bad idea).

Comment: when I change my statement to if(eval(Profile_Filter)) I get missing ) in parenthetical error.

Comment: Then there is a syntax error in your eval'd code. For instance, check the statement `Degree_Filter += '(gAssessorsCompanyAssociationsArray[i].Degree.indexOf("' + Degree[j] + '") > 0';`, there seems to be a closing brace missing.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with eval. Is it possible to do it without eval since it is not recommended?